# remote into Rpi get a wall of text how to remove?

Tags: raspbian

I just got a rPi and am struggling to find a file, in the Linux systems.

I have remote access to it via Putty and when I get in I get the following text:
"the programs included with debian GNU/Linux ...." - a wall of text about Debian and Linux.

I want to remove it as I have a python script that runs at login onto the rPi.

Had a look in some areas like MOTD and some bashrc files but can't seem to find it.

Any help would be awesome. 
Many thanks,
Matt E

Comment: The file you're looking for is `/etc/motd`.

Comment: 6 or 7 lines is hardly a "wall of text"

Answer (score 3):

The quick answer is to simply remove this file: `motd` in `/etc/`

Instead of removing it I recommend you move it to a file with another name if you want to restore it later:

```
sudo mv /etc/motd /etc/motd.old
```

If you still want it to show a message, but another message of your own choice, you can edit the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/motd
```